# When using a delimiter, how would I combine \\s+ with [^A-Z0-9a-z]?

Tags: java

So right now the code I have is

```
dataScan.useDelimiter("[^A-Z0-9a-z]");
```

and what I want to do is add `\\s+` to it to remove the whitespace as well, where am I supposed to add it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use predefined character class `\s` inside user-defined character class, like this:

```
"[^A-Z0-9a-z\\s]"
```

You do not need to add `+` to it, because scanner handles repeated delimiters.